# display random posts on index.php instead of latest

Tags: posts

I have the settings so only one post (which is by default the most recent) displays with index.php

my current working code

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

How could I change to code to display a random post from any category/date?

It just needs to be one post if that makes a difference.

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following code in your theme functions.php file.

```
function one_random_post_on_home_page( $query )
{
    if ( ! ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) )
        return;

    $query->set( 'orderby ', 'rand' );
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 1 );
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'one_random_post_on_home_page' );
```

I'm assuming when you say index.php you mean your blogs home page. The index.php file in your theme can be used for many other areas of your website so making any alterations in that file might have undesired effects else where.

Comment: yes sorry, i did mean theme index.

Comment: is this code more reliable than: <?php global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&orderby=rand' ); ?>
     
                   <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

Comment: @bracketboy - using query_posts() for what you have asked for is bad. You can read more here: http://developer.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/querying-posts-without-query_posts/

Answer (score 0):

Combine the two codes above like this:

```
function one_random_post_on_home_page( $query )
{
    if ( ! ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) )
        return;
        query_posts(array('orderby' => 'rand', 'showposts' => 1));
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'one_random_post_on_home_page' );
```

Answer (score -2):

Try posting this code above your current code:

```
<?php query_posts(array('orderby' => 'rand', 'showposts' => 1)); ?>
```